# MySql taking random element from distinct random category

Tags: mysql

I have a table images, which has rows `i_id | imgpath | category`

I would like to choose 60 distinct categories randomly and a random image from each category.

So far I have a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(category), i_id, imgpath FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 60
```

But it sometimes produces more than one image from the same category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using `GROUP_CONCAT` to have a comma separated list of imgpath for each category so that images for each category will be ordered randomly then `SUBSTRING_INDEX` over comma separated list of imgpath to pick one image

```
SELECT category, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(imgpath ORDER BY RAND())
,',',1) imgpath
FROM images 
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 60
```